# What happens to Unsullied after this death?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones*, after their beloved queen's death, will the Unsullied follow the new king or will they return to their home?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are going to Naath, as said by Grey Worm:

> We sail for the Isle of Naath.

They are free people and seem to be following Grey Worm and of course, Naath was Missandei's home. It's a throwback to their past conversation where Missandei expressed going back there. So it seems they are going to Naath and might become the protectors of Missandei's people there.

Comment: Actually, they're more likely to catch a fever and die. *“Strangers…do not live long upon the Isle of Butterflies."* (from the books)

Comment: Doesn't Grey Worm explicitly mention fulfilling Dany's wish of a slavery-free world? I'm pretty sure the remaining Unsullied are setting sail to go do that.

Comment: Naath is a land frequently raided by slavers, so it seems reasonable that if they wanted to both fight slavery and honour Missandei, they could do worse than go protect Naath.